# Can 'symmetric_different_update' work with list that was converted to a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have a problem when writing code with `symmetric_different_update`:

```
morning = ['Java', 'C', 'Ruby', 'Lisp', 'C#']
afternoon = ['Python', 'C#', 'Java', 'C', 'Ruby']
set(afternoon).symmetric_difference_update(morning)
print(set(afternoon))
```

My output:

```
{'Java', 'Python', 'C', 'C#', 'Ruby'}
```

In the case `morning` and `afternoon` are sets, its work normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `morning` and `afternoon` are sets, it also doesn't work:

```
>>> morning = {'Java', 'C', 'Ruby', 'Lisp', 'C#'}
>>> afternoon = {'Python', 'C#', 'Java', 'C', 'Ruby'}
>>> set(afternoon).symmetric_difference_update(morning)
>>> print(set(afternoon))
{'Java', 'Python', 'Ruby', 'C#', 'C'}
```

The problem comes from the fact that you call the method on a copy of the set/list. To fix this, you could not use the `_update` variant and assign back to the same name:

```
>>> morning = ['Java', 'C', 'Ruby', 'Lisp', 'C#']
>>> afternoon = ['Python', 'C#', 'Java', 'C', 'Ruby']
>>> afternoon = list(set(afternoon).symmetric_difference(morning))
>>> print(afternoon)
['Lisp', 'Python']
```